# why keras gives me desired results for my Entity Embedding but not pytorch?

Tags: keras, pytorch, categorical-data, embeddings

I tried to build `Entity Embeddings` of categorical data from a dataset. 
I took a dataset - "Bike share”.This dataset shows number of bike share/rent/sales in every month.The month column has $12$ categories.

I wanted to make 12 Entity embeddings or 12 vectors, one for each month.I trained the embeddings against the bike share/rent/sales or i should say i used bike share/rent/sales as my labels.To visualize the embeddings I plotted the learned Embeddings/vectors.
On a 3D graph and I expected that the months with similar sales will be close together on the 3D graph but I didn’t get the expected results.
In fact when I made the same model in `Keras` I got the results I was expecting. For example the batch size of $8$ works very well in keras but same batch size increases loss in `pytorch`. In `pytorch` big batch size($40$) reduces loss.

Would you be kind enough to have a look at my code in pytorch. It’s a very short code and will only take $10$ minutes.

Here's the link to my `Pytorch` code - https://github.com/akshay6893/Entity_Embeddings/blob/master/Entity%20Embedding%20in%20Pytorch%202.ipynb

and `keras` code - 
https://github.com/akshay6893/Entity_Embeddings/blob/master/Entity_Embeddings_keras.ipynb

Here’s the data online - https://www.kaggle.com/marklvl/bike-sharing-dataset.(very small dataset)